# Classic ASP connecting to localdb for SQL Server

Tags: asp-classic, connection-string, legacy-code

Can anyone explain why this works

```
Conn.Open "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Server=tcp:myazurename.database.windows.net;Database=People;Uid=MyUid;Pwd=MyPwd;Encrypt=yes;"
```

and this doesn't

```
Conn.Open "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Server=(localdb)\v11.0;Database=People;Uid=MyUid;Pwd=MyPwd;Encrypt=yes;"
```

I copied my live azure database locally for dev work in Classic ASP and the error message is

> Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server error '80004005'
>   [DBNETLIB][ConnectionOpen (Connect()).] SQL Server does not exist or access denied.

Azure SQL server version: 11.0.9231
Local SQL server version: 11.0.2318

I can connect using the same details on SQL Server Management Studio so its not a user permissions thing...

Under Security for the server, the user has public server role, the user mapping for the 'People' database is everything except db_denydatareader and db_denydatawriter.

I have also tried (localdb)\\v11.0 which doesn't make a difference.

Any ideas?

Comment: `(localdb)\v11.0` doesn't look like a Server / Local Machine name, are you sure that is your instance? Would expect something like `MACHINENAME\INSTANCENAME` if it's SQL Server Express it would be `MACHINENAME\SQLEXPRESS`.

Comment: Aw..your using a [localDB Automatic instance](https://www.connectionstrings.com/sqlconnection/localdb-automatic-instance/), that might be the problem. *"The first connection to LocalDB will create and start the instance, this takes some time and **might cause a connection timeout failure**. If this happens, wait a bit and connect again."* I don't think it's supported by ADODB, in effect it tries to create a new database instance for you.

Comment: In fact your not likely to see any usage of `SQLOLEDB` especially for SQL Server 2012, you should be using the SQL Server Native Client. See [SQL Server Native Client 11.0 OLE DB Provider connection strings](https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2012/).

Comment: Thanks @Lankymart I tried SQLNCLI but got this error
ADODB.Connection error '800a0e7a'
Provider cannot be found. It may not be properly installed. So persisted with SQLOLEDB as it works for the azure conn string

Comment: installing a new instance now - will try to set a proper  name rather than (localdb)\v11.0 and will let you know how it goes

Comment: What are you installing? Just need to change the connection string to one of from the link I sent you and use the correctly formed `Server` attribute. If you have already install SQL Server Express the default instance is named `SQLEXPRESS` other wise it's a non express version of SQL Server then it will install a default instance against the machine, so just use `MACHINENAME`.

Comment: in my sql configuration manager, there was no instance running - believe it or not - but I could still connect on (localdb)\v11.0. Somehow the localdb seems to be different from an actual instance. So i ran my installer again and I now have localhost\SQL2012INST1 running but I am getting the same error on SQLOLEDB! Wait! Its working now

Comment: OK so I believe the answer is as follows: It doesn't like (LocalDb)\V11.0 it wants a proper instance name like you said in the first place. MACHINENAME\INSTANCENAME OR localhost\INSTANCENAME which I am using as this is going to be replicated for other devs. Also, you DONT NEED two back slashes! My problem is I somehow didn't have a local instance installed. Thanks or your help @Lankymart

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK so I believe the answer is as follows: It doesn't like (LocalDb)\V11.0 it wants a proper instance name like you said in the first place. MACHINENAME\INSTANCENAME OR localhost\INSTANCENAME which I am using as this is going to be replicated for other devs. Also, you DONT NEED two back slashes! My problem is I somehow didn't have a local instance installed. Thanks or your help @Lankymart